# About Case Ignore of MySQL

Tags: mysql

The column name is Case Ignore with MySQL 5.0, but, as for the table name, is Case Exact true?

Answer (score 2):

This boils down to whether your filesystem is case sensitive, and what the `lower_case_table_names` variable is set to.

See [Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) for the full details.